# Importing Excel file using url using read.xls

Tags: r, gdata

I'm trying to use read.xls from gdata to import an Excel file directly into R.  I'm on a Windows machine running 64 bit R.

I have checked my PATH variable for perl and I appear to have that set correctly, so that doesn't appear to be a problem. Here's my code, and I've attached my error below.  Does anyone have any pointers on how I can get this done?

```
require(RCurl)
require(gdata)
url <- "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27644144/NADAC%2020140101.xls"
test <- read.xls(url)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error in xls2sep(xls, sheet, verbose = verbose, ..., method = method,  : 
Intermediate file 'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeoJNxP\file338c26156d7.csv' missing!
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:\STRAWB~1\perl\bin\perl.exe" "C:/Users/Me/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/gdata/perl/xls2csv.pl"  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27644144/NADAC%2020140101.xls" "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeoJNxP\file338c26156d7.csv" "1"' had status 22 
Error in file.exists(tfn) : invalid 'file' argument
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@G.G is correct that `read.xls` does not support `https`. However, if you simply replace the `https` with `http` in the url you should be able to download the file.

Give this a try:

```
require(RCurl)
require(gdata)
url <- "http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27644144/NADAC%2020140101.xls"
test <- read.xls(url)
```

Answer (score 5):

`read.xls` supports `http` and `ftp` but does not support `https`.  Download it first and then use `read.xls` with the downloaded file.