# read.xls (gdata) - from an https url

Tags: r, https, gdata

I'm trying to read in an excel file from a URL: 
https://www.misoenergy.org/Library/Repository/Market%20Reports/20140507_sr_la.xls

I can download the file, and read it in using read.xls from the gdata package no problem.

But I get an error when trying to read it in directly.

```
    Unable to open file 'https://www.misoenergy.org/Library/Repository/Market%20Reports/20140507_sr_la.xls'.
    Error in xls2sep(xls, sheet, verbose = verbose, ..., method = method,  : 
      Intermediate file '/tmp/RtmptxiYS1/file42f8532a0129.csv' missing
```

I've tried this: 
[Importing Excel file using url using read.xls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738463/importing-excel-file-using-url-using-read-xls) but the 's' in 'https' is required.

Comment: Download it with your browser. Then read it from disk.

Comment: this needs to be a purely automated process. I can download the file using a system("wget file dest") 

but would prefer to not do this.

Comment: R has problems with `https://` in calls to `file()`. You need to explain further why your "preferences" are compelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(gdata)
tmp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://www.misoenergy.org/Library/Repository/Market%20Reports/20140507_sr_la.xls", 
              destfile=tmp, method="curl")

read.xls(tmp, skip=2)
unlink(tmp)
```

Comment: ... or `method="wget"`

Comment: Thanks. Worked great.