# Import in R the specified worksheed of a .xls from url

Tags: r, url, import, xls

I'm interested in importing directly in R a portion of the .xls associated with the following url. The .xls has two different spreadsheets. I want to import the table that starts in the 5th row in the second spreadsheets. An attempt is the following:

```
require(gdata)
url = "https://www.philadelphiafed.org/-/media/research-and-data/real-time-center/real-time-data/data-files/files/routput_first_second_third.xls?la=en.xls"
dataset = read.xls(url, sheet=2, header=T, skip=4)
```

The error that I get is:

```
Error in file.exists(tfn) : invalid 'file' argument
```

I'm working in Windows. The source of the .xls is [here](https://www.philadelphiafed.org/research-and-data/real-time-center/real-time-data/data-files/routput) under the name "All available observations". You are very welcome use different packages.

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738463/importing-excel-file-using-url-using-read-xls, change https to http, and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to download file then you can read it.

```
require(gdata)
url = "https://www.philadelphiafed.org/-/media/research-and-data/real-time-center/real-time-data/data-files/files/routput_first_second_third.xls?la=en.xls"

download.file(url, destfile="file.xls")

data<- read.xls("file.xls", header=TRUE, pattern="Rank", header=TRUE, sheet=2, skip=3)
```

Comment: Running you code produce a NULL data. Anyway, data=read.xls("file.xls", header=TRUE, sheet=2, skip=3) does the trick. I suggest you to consider editing your answer with this line of code. Thank you very much!