# R: Webscraping a xls page

Tags: r

I am trying to webscrape a xls page of oil stocks.

I tried :

```
 library("readxl") 
 df <-read_excel("https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist_xls/W_EPC0_SAX_YCUOK_MBBLw.xls",sheet="Data 1")
```

but I get an error message:
Error: `path` does not exist

Thank you for your help.

Comment: take a look at this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738463/importing-excel-file-using-url-using-read-xls

Comment: I am not sure readxl supports accessing a file over the internet.  One work around is to use `download.file` and then read the file from your local drive.

Comment: @Dave2e is correct. This method works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368628/read-excel-file-from-a-url-using-the-readxl-package

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but I could not get the correct dates. I tried df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date, "%m/%d/%Y") but then got NA